# Как заменить только первое вхождение в строке?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно выполнить `UPDATE` строки и у поля `parent` со значением `14 11 10 11 52` (это примерное значение, на деле оно будет вообще любым) удалить первое вхождение `11`, а второе не трогать. Как это сделать?

Comment: Сам формат выбран неудачно, я считаю. Трудно НЕ найти 11 в 111 Если бы в качестве разделителя была запятая, то безошибочно искать можно было бы через FIND_IN_SET(),

Comment: @artoodetoo на самом деле у меня цифры разделяются запятыми, так что такой проблемы не будет, я просто привёл случайный пример строки.

Comment: @artoodetoo, а нельзя ли строку скастить к сету?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не уверен, что понимаю вопрос :) FIND_IN_SET() можно использовать как с полем типа set, так и со строковым значением, в котором есть значения-через-запятую. С результатом GROUP_CONCAT(), например :D (Можно не значит нужно.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть удобная функция [INSTR(str, substr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) для поиска первого вхождения подстроки. Режем, клеим, получаем удаление первой подстроки.
Важно не забыть про WHERE, а то отрежется и где не надо!

```
UPDATE example 
SET parent = CONCAT(
  LEFT(parent, INSTR(parent, '11') - 1), 
  SUBSTRING(parent, INSTR(parent, '11') + LENGTH('11') + 1)
)
WHERE INSTR(parent, '11')
```

Если же нам захочется не удалить, а заменить первую '11' на 'xxx', например:

```
UPDATE example 
SET parent = CONCAT(
  REPLACE(LEFT(parent, INSTR(parent, '11') + LENGTH('11') - 1), '11', 'xxx'),
  SUBSTRING(parent, INSTR(parent, '11') + LENGTH('11'))
)
WHERE INSTR(parent, '11')
```

Comment: `2112 11 17` - неверно же?

Comment: Согласен. Но автор привел пример только с двухбуквенниками ))) Я считаю сам формат выбран очень неудачно. Отметил комментарием к вопросу.

Comment: Ага, я на тот комментарий сначала ответил, потом прочитал описание функции и удалил :) У меня вроде нормально должно работать? Что-то фиддл ошибку теперь пишет :(

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем везде по краям пробелы, находим первое вхождение, конкатенируем через пробел то, что до него, и то, что после, затем избавляемся от пробелов по краям.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4416e/1/0

```
create table tbl (id int not null auto_increment primary key, col nvarchar(128));
insert into tbl(col) values (N'14 11 10 11 52');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'11 10 11 52');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'14 10 11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'11 2 11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'11 11 11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'111 11 11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'12 112 11');
insert into tbl(col) values (N'12 211 11');
update tbl set col = concat(trim(left(col, instr(concat(N' ', col, N' '), N' 11 ') - 1)), N' ', trim(mid(col, instr(concat(N' ', col, N' '), N' 11 ') - 1 + length(N' 11 '))));
select * from tbl;
```

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость, но я уже нашёл более простой способ.

Comment: @DeFF, он не более простой, он неправильный. Проверь на строке `2112 11 17`

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае сработает вот это:

```
UPDATE example SET parent = CONCAT
(
  SUBSTR(parent, 1, INSTR(parent, '11') - 1), 
  SUBSTR(parent, INSTR(parent, '11') + LENGTH('11'))
);
```

Comment: `2112 11 17` - неверно же?

Comment: @Qwertiy всё будет работать. Я не написал здесь, но у меня цифры разделяются запятыми и проблем не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функции [LOCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), [INSERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) и [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length):

```
INSERT(originalvalue, LOCATE('11', originalvalue), CHAR_LENGTH('11'), '')
```